# Automation: Can't inspect GUI controls with Spy++

Tags: c++, .net, automation, ui-automation, spy++

I'm trying to automate a desktop application but I can't inspect its elements using tools such as Spy++,  Inspect.exe, UI Verify... The application is old aparently built with C++.

Is there anything I can do?

I've thought about reproducing the application communication with the server via code, but I wasn't able to identify HTTP requests/responses between them.

[Spy++ screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEBo8.png)

Comment: Could this be a 64bit / 32bit problem?

Comment: Both (application and Spy++) are running in 32bit mode

Comment: This can happen if spy and the spied on app don't run at same UAC level (admin vs non admin, etc.).

Comment: Both (application and Spy++) are running under the same privilleges.